# Enhanced \oint to emphasize circulation

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

I'm looking for a symbol that merges `\iint` and `\oint` together (a dedicated package, if it could exist, would provide something like `\oiint` and `\oiiint`).

The purpose of `\oint` is to show that the integration path is closed (it is often used in the definition of the circulation), but the adding one (or two) more integral it is emphasized that the integral is calculated over a surface (`\oiint`) or over a volume (`\oiiint`).

Do these symbols exist in the world of LaTeX?

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

wasysym, txfonts, and pxfonts packages provide these symbols. It is always a good idea to check the **comprehensive** latex [symbol list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Comment: The `unicode-math` package also provides these, though it also messes with other math commands.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\oiint \hspace{-13.5pt} \int` I was able to create an `\oiiint` replacement. It uses the `\oiint` from the `esint` library.
 (`\usepackage{esint}`)

Below you can see a before and after. It's a little crammed but it works! This is the only way I got this to work in MikTeX with the default font Computer Serif Modern.

[image: Before and after]

Comment: So how does this scale when using `10pt`, `11pt` or `12pt` document class option?